# Drop down menu with integer values does not stay selected after refreshing the page

Tags: php, html

I have a drop down menu and the user can select a number from one to four. Here is the code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['Submit1'])) {
        $SiteNumber = $_POST['SN'];
        $fileName = 'test.txt';
        $lines = file($fileName);
        $lines[0]="Site_number= ". $SiteNumber;
        file_put_contents($fileName, implode($lines));
    } else {
        $fileName = 'test.txt';

        $lines = file($fileName);

        $SiteNumber=explode(" ",$lines[0]);
        $SiteNumber=$SiteNumber[1];
    }
    ?>
    <form action="test.php" name ="form1" Method ="POST">
    Site Number:
    <select selected="selected" name="SN" VALUE="<?PHP print $SiteNumber ; ?>">

         <?php $attr= 'selected="selected"'; ?>

         <option VALUE="1"  <?php echo $SiteNumber == '1' ? $attr : '';  ?>>1</option>
         <option VALUE="2"  <?php echo $SiteNumber== '2' ?   $attr : ''; ?>>2</option>
         <option VALUE="3"  <?php echo $SiteNumber == '3' ? $attr : ''; ?>>3</option>
         <option VALUE="4"  <?php echo $SiteNumber== '4' ? $attr : ''; ?>>4</option>

    </select>

    <Input Type = "Submit" Name ="Submit1" Value = "Save Parameters">
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The  problem is that the selected number goes back to 1 when I refresh the page although it is supposed to show the selected value and read it from the text file. The error I am getting in the log is :
Undefined variable: SiteNumber

so I have tried (in) $_POST['SN'] but no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have selected="selected"  in your select tag? It only belongs in your option tag. Also, the select tag should not have a value assigned either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this line `$lines[0]="Site_number= ". $SiteNumber;`

I think this is a resource and not an array. You may have to set this as an array before you can assign a value to it. try adding this line instead

```
$line=array();
$line[0]="Site_number= ". $SiteNumber;
```

Oh, I tried running your code basically how you have it, and got it to work - I saw the value coming from `$SiteNumber = $_POST['SN'];`

here this worked for me:

```
if (isset($_POST['Submit1'])) {
    $SiteNumber = $_POST['SN'];
    $fileName = 'test.txt';
    $lines = fopen($fileName, "w");
    $line=array();
    $line[0]="site number= ".$SiteNumber;

    fwrite($lines, implode($line));
    fclose($lines);
```

}
else {

```
    $fileName = 'test.txt';

    $lines = fopen($fileName, "r");
    $SiteNumber = fgets($lines);

    $SiteNumber=explode(" ",$SiteNumber);
    $SiteNumber = $SiteNumber[2];
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You have to change dropdown to like this

```
Site Number: 
<select name="SN">
 <?php $attr= 'selected="selected"'; ?>

 <option VALUE="1"  <?php echo $SiteNumber == '1' ? $attr : '';  ?>>1</option>
 <option VALUE="2"  <?php echo $SiteNumber== '2' ?   $attr : ''; ?>>2</option>
 <option VALUE="3"  <?php echo $SiteNumber == '3' ? $attr : ''; ?>>3</option>
 <option VALUE="4"  <?php echo $SiteNumber== '4' ? $attr : ''; ?>>4</option>

</select>
```

Comment: I think the issue the OP is having is that `$SiteNumber` is not getting defined from the post variable `$_POST['SN']`